# Supplying multiple names in a single olcRefintAttribute value is unsupported and will be disallowed in a future version

Tags: ldap, openldap

Since a few time with OpenLDAP 2.6.2 on AlpineLinux 3.15, running the `slapcat` command generates this warning:

`Supplying multiple names in a single olcRefintAttribute value is unsupported and will be disallowed in a future version`

The `olcRefintAttribute` attribute from the refint overlay has the value `memberof member owner`.

How can I fix this warning? I a migration required?

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be fixed by giving `olcRefintAttribute` a single value, multiple times.

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// << EOF
dn: olcOverlay={0}refint,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcRefintAttribute
-
add: olcRefintAttribute
olcRefintAttribute: memberof
olcRefintAttribute: member
olcRefintAttribute: manager
olcRefintAttribute: owner
EOF
```